# Monotouch: How to dismiss any open UIAlertViews

Tags: ios, uiview, xamarin.ios

I need to be able to find and dismiss all open UIAlertViews in my application.

I have tried the following with no success:

```
foreach (var window in UIApplication.SharedApplication.Windows)
{
     foreach (var view in window.Subviews)
     {
          if (view is UIAlertView)
               (view as UIAlertView).DismissWithClickedButtonIndex(0, false);
     }
}
```

and also:

```
foreach (var view in _rootNavigationController.VisibleViewController.View)
{
     if (view is UIAlertView)
     {
           (view as UIAlertView).DismissWithClickedButtonIndex(0, false);
     }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not subclass `UIAlertView`, override `Show`/`Hide` methods in which register/unregister `UIAlertView`'s in list? Then, implement `HideAll` method in which close them all in loop.

I only see the problem in 3rd party libraries, which are don't know about that subclass.